# Large number of markers adding in android google map version 2 unable to execute Progress update of asynchronous background task

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

```
    public class PositionUpdate1  extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Location> 
 {

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

              super.onPreExecute();
              dialog = new ProgressDialog(NearByAttractions2.this);
              dialog.setMessage("Loading Places........");
              dialog.setCancelable(false);
              dialog.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Location doInBackground(Void...arg0) 
        {

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(5000);
            }
            catch(InterruptedException e)
            {

                e.printStackTrace();
            }

             runOnUiThread(new Thread()
             {
                    public void run() 
                    {
                         String xml = ParseXMLMethods2.getXML();
                        Document doc = ParseXMLMethods2.XMLfromString(xml);
                        NodeList children = doc.getElementsByTagName(KEY_ITEM);
                        for (int i = 0; i < children.getLength(); i++) 
                        {                           
                          Element e = (Element)children.item(i);

                          alist.add(ParseXMLMethods2.getValue(e,KEY_TITLE));
                        }

                          arr = new String[alist.size()];
                          alist.toArray(arr);

                         int status = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getBaseContext());

                      // Showing status
                      if(status!=ConnectionResult.SUCCESS){ // Google Play Services are not available

                          int requestCode = 10;
                          Dialog dialog = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(status, NearByAttractions2.this, requestCode);
                          dialog.show();
                      }else 
                      { 

                          LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

                          // Creating a criteria object to retrieve provider
                          Criteria criteria = new Criteria();

                          // Getting the name of the best provider
                          provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria, true);

                          locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(provider, 20000, 0, NearByAttractions2.this);
                          map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                      }





                    }
                });

            publishProgress();
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Location loc) 
        {
            dialog.dismiss();

            map.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new OnInfoWindowClickListener() 
                {
                    @Override
                    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) 
                    {
                       Intent intent = new Intent(NearByAttractions2.this,Activity2.class);
                       intent.putExtra("Clubname", marker.getTitle());
                       intent.putExtra("Username", Username);
                       intent.putExtra("ID2", UserID);
                       startActivity(intent);
                    }
                });
            {

        }

    }

        @Override
         protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) 
         {
            dialog.dismiss();

             geoCoder = new Geocoder(NearByAttractions2.this, Locale.getDefault());  
             try 
             {

                 for(int i = 0;i<arr.length;i++)

                 {
                    addresses = geoCoder.getFromLocationName(arr[i], 1);

                   if(addresses.toString().contains("Address"))
                   {

                     Address address = addresses.get(0);

                      double lat = address.getLatitude();
                      double lng = address.getLongitude();

                      combine = new LatLng(lat, lng);
                      map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                     .title(arr[i])
                     .position(combine));

                   }
                  else
                  {

                  }

              }
            } catch (IOException e) 
            {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"some attractions are unavailable at this moment due to slow internet connection",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

         }

 }
```

in the above code my requirement is map open after populating array mentioned at doing background method and then markers will add whenever I drag map means after populating array I want to use UI component and marker adding will be done at background under Progress update.How can I fulfill my requirement without clustering in android?

Comment: If large number od markers is the matter you can use android marker clustering.This is really good library.https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/utility/marker-clustering

Comment: 02-02 03:08:59.339: E/dalvikvm(4422): Could not find class 'com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.ClusteringDemoActivity', referenced from method com.google.maps.android.utils.demo.MainActivity.onCreate
getting above error while want to run map clustring demo in android